# Automatically generating text images and corresponding CSS with Sass?

Tags: html, css, imagemagick, sass

tl;dr: Are there currently anything for Sass that does something like this, taking an ImageMagick generated image and put it into the image folder and specify its width and height automatically?

```
h2.anthony {
    /* image replacement CSS here */
    @magick-image: "convert -fill blue -font Candice -pointsize 72 label:Anthony header-anthony.png";
}
```

(The ImageMagick command is based on this example: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label)

Resultant CSS:

```
h2.anthony {
    /* image replacement CSS here */
    background: url(img/header-anthony.png) no-repeat;
    width: 275px;
    height: 79px;
}
```

I have to use images and not Web Fonts, Cufon, sIFR etc. because the site is in Chinese and Chinese fonts are huge.

Back story:

I am working on a new website with quite a lot of text in many pages and their header text should be displayed in a specific font with a gradient effect on it.

Right now, even if I use CSS sprites and put all the header text with the required effect into the same image, I still have to measure the width of each row and type it into my stylesheet by hand. It gets even more cumbersome as pages are added or removed or the length of the longest row of text changes.

I am looking for ways to automate this. I already figured out how to recreate the effect with ImageMagick so I can generate each header image with one command, but I still have to measure the width of the image myself.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems you already know what images need to be created? If so why not just create all the images with imagemagick, the use [compass sprites with the `$<map>-sprite-dimensions` option](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/customization-options/) to generate the css with dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

There just happens to be a Compass extension that lets you use ImageMagick.  I've never used it, but it looks interesting.

https://github.com/StanAngeloff/compass-magick

Comment: I've looked into this but it doesn't seem to create text images. :(